# How can I integrate over the center of mass when treating connected correlation function?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, correlation-functions

Hi I studied the phase transition using the text book statistical physics of field, Kardar.
But I can't understand the process (1.28) to (1.30).
Does anyone can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the author is doing is performing a change of integration variables. The original integral is in terms of the variables $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}'$, which I will relabel to $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$:
$$
k_B T \chi = \int d^3\vec{r}_1 d^3\vec{r}_2 \langle m(\vec{r}_1) m(\vec{r}_2) \rangle_c
$$
As the author argues, the connected correlation function is a function of only $\vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2$, rather than $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$ separately. We can therefore perform the following change of integration variables, which has unit Jacobian:
$$
\vec{R} = \frac{\vec{r}_1 + \vec{r}_2}{2}, \quad \vec{r} = \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2
$$
The susceptibility is then given by
$$
k_B T \chi = \int d^3 \vec{R} d^3 \vec{r} \langle m(\vec{r}) m(\vec{0}) \rangle_c
$$
The integral over $\vec{R}$ can then be immediately performed; it results in a factor $V$, where $V$ is the volume of the system.

Comment: I'm so sorry but how can I change of variables when I define R and r?
I can not write Jacobian in this case... plz help me more?

Comment: What’s the obstruction? Do you know how to perform a change of variables in a multi-dimensional integral? If not, then you should probably review your multivariable calculus before going further with Kardar.